# Screen capture - Weird gray area

Tags: swift, uiimage

I am trying to get a capture of the screen that I am currently on so when I overlay my next view controller I can make that the image view behind it and make it appear as its semi-transparent. This was working but now it produces some weird gray in the middle. Here is the code I am using:

```
    func requestOverride(overrideReason : String, notificationName : Notification.Name) {

    captureScreen { (image) in
        ManagerOverride.image = image

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "ManagerOverride", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "overrideNav") as! UINavigationController
        let over = vc.viewControllers.first as! ManagerOverrideViewController
        let _ = over.view
        over.overrideReason.text = overrideReason
        over.notifyName = notificationName
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.currentViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func captureScreen(completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
let view = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.currentViewController()!.view!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
completion(image!)
}
```

and here is what I am getting back:

[image]

I have no idea why its doing that

Answer (score 0):

Rendering views in context is not a 100% method unfortunately. Not all view and layer properties are saved on the screenshot. One I know of is the `layer.mask` (or potentially the state of `masksToBounds` flag). This may be your problem, some view uses a mask, on screen it's masked out but on the screenshot it is rendered like the mask wasn't there.